# EmberJS 2.x , resorting or filtering records from store via actions

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

Consider the following code in your js file:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('team');
    }
});
```

In your html file, you might have something like this:

```
{{#each model as |team|}}
<ul>
    <li>{{team.name}}</li>
    <li>{{team.email}}</li>
    <li>{{team.state}}</li>
    <li>{{team.position}}</li>
</ul><br>___<br>
{{/each}}
```

And the result would be something like

- Bob Smith
- bob.smith@bobsmithinc.com
- NY
- Leader

  ---
- Jane Smith
- jane.smith@janesmithinc.com
- NY
- Finance

  ---
- John Doe
- john.doe@janesmithinc.com
- CA
- Support

The question is, how would you go about sorting or filter this data after it's displayed?  For example, if I want to sort by alphabetical order by name, or email, or lets say I only want to display someone in NY, and not CA.... or maybe type as I search, so if I type 'inc.com'... anyone that has that in their record will show?

My guess is this occurs in the controller via an Action?  I just don't understand how to grab the store data (WITHOUT a network request) and resort or filter the data that's already there. I know you can use 'peek', but am unsure how to display the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**to sort data in model** you have to create new computed property in controller like so

```
sortedList: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),
sortProperties: ['name:desc'], // properties to use for sorting
```

then in your template you can use it

```
{{#each sortedList as |team|}}
```

so then by modifying `sortProperties` to e.g. `[state:asc]` you are able to change sort order which can be in action handler

Comment: one quick question .... how do I make it dynamic, so I can put in actions?  I'm not sure how to pass in sortedList or sortProperties inside the action, unless it just gets nested inside the action?